# Solution for inner page css file for better performance

Tags: html, css, performance, optimization

When I design a page I will create a CSS file so all of my `selectors` will store in this file, for first page, inner pages and all another pages which I have in my website.

But in this mode, when I trying to check my site in `GTMetrics.com` or `webpagetest.org` or another websites, they inform me I have many selectors in my css file which I didn't use in page so they asked me to optimize my css file ! but I use that selectors in another pages.

Now my question is, what is the best way to store css selectors ? should I have a separate css file for each page and load with `link` in each page or should I have separate css file and load with `@import` in css file or store all selectors in one file (like now) ?

Comment: How are you including your CSS? Using `<style>` tag or using `<link>` tag?

Comment: @PraveenKumar `<link>` tag

Answer (score 0):

First of all, those sites are just tools to help you optimizing your site. They don't know everything, that's why they say you use a lot of unused selector.

I don't know how much the styles are changed and on what pages. But if your styles are somewhat equal with minor differences, you should keep those in one file.
If, for instance, the homepage is completely different from the other pages, or if some pages have big differences, you should use one global stylesheet and multiple page specific stylesheets.

Read more about this topic in this great article by CSS guru Chris Coyier: ["One, Two or Three"](http://css-tricks.com/one-two-three/)

Answer (score 0):

one css file is the best way 
if you make separate file for every page 
on every page a unique file loads 
so the time increases  and performance decrease

one css file caches itself and dont load everytime 
so you done right 
ignore the warnings